# How to test a function that uses the window.screen.width in jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, window, width, screen

I'm trying to test this function in **jest**,
But I cannot override, resize the screen or create a virtual dom.

I'm running this testing on node.
ps: I tried to use jsdom but I failed.

*functions.js*

```js
export const getScreenWidth = () => {
  const screenWidth = window.screen.width;
  if (screenWidth <= 425) return "mobile";
  if (screenWidth <= 768) return "tablet";
  if (screenWidth <= 1024) return "laptopSm";
  if (screenWidth <= 1440) return "laptopLg";
  if (screenWidth <= 2560) return "HD";
  return screenWidth;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to make this mock and it worked but I don't really know if this is the right way to do so.

```js
const mockScreen = (size) => {
      global.window = {};
      global.window.screen = {};
      global.window.screen.width = size;
    };
```

so the final test will be

```js
describe("getScreenWidth()", () => {
  it.only("returns a string representing the width of the screen", () => {
    const mockScreen = (size) => {
      global.window = {};
      global.window.screen = {};
      global.window.screen.width = size;
    };
    mockScreen(425);
    expect(jsf.getScreenWidth()).toBe("mobile");
    mockScreen(2560);
    expect(jsf.getScreenWidth()).toBe("HD");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The screen can be mocked by overriding the global screen variable.

Example:

```
const mockScreen = (size) => {
  const { screen } = window.screen;
  delete window.screen;
  window.screen = {
    ...screen,
    width: size
  };
};

test("getScreenWidth", () => {
  mockScreen(300);
  expect(getScreenWidth()).toBe("mobile");
  mockScreen(1025);
  expect(getScreenWidth()).toBe("laptopLg");
});
```

Comment: I got this error
`The error below may be caused by using the wrong test environment, see https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string.        
    Consider using the "jsdom" test environment.`

Answer (score 0):

If you work with react testing library simulate a resize like this

```
global.innerWidth = 1024;
global.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
```

then expect your function to return the right size

I tested a custom hook like

```
function useWindowSize() {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(window.innerHeight);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {
      setWidth(window.innerWidth);
      setHeight(window.innerHeight);
    };
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    };
  });

  return { width, height };
}
```

this way

```
function TestUseWindowSize() {
  const { height, width } = useWindowSize();
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 data-testid="height">{height}</h1>
      <h1 data-testid="width">{width}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

describe('useWindowSize Custom Hook', () => {
  it('should return height and width', () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<TestUseWindowSize />);
    // screen defaults by render function
    expect(getByTestId('height')).toHaveTextContent(/768/);
    expect(getByTestId('width')).toHaveTextContent(/1024/);

    global.innerWidth = 1000;
    global.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
    expect(getByTestId('width')).toHaveTextContent(/1000/);
  });
});
```

Comment: I got that you're testing a component that uses the hook, but how would you test only the hook itself?.